# How to change download location for VS Code extensions?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm having difficulty installing and updating extensions in VS Code on my work computer. When I try, I get:

```
Error while updating 'PowerShell' extension. Please check the log for more details.
```

I'm getting the following in my logs:

```
[2022-05-05 09:14:41.193] [renderer1] [error] ["Error: XHR failed"," at XMLHttpRequest.R.onerror (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Program%20Files/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:21:27097)"]
[2022-05-05 09:14:41.196] [renderer1] [error] XHR failed: Error: XHR failed at XMLHttpRequest.R.onerror (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Program%20Files/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:21:27097)
```

I'm also seeing blocked connections in our firewall log to ms-code.gallerycdn.azure.cn, which I'm guessing is my problem. Our corporate firewall geoblocks China; is there a way to get VS Code to use another CDN location?

Comment: I notice a little interest in this question; FYI, it appears to be a problem with VS Code choosing to use the China CDN (azure.cn) instead of the global one (vsassets.io). I've opened a ticket with Microsoft who are looking into why my non-China connection is being served from azure.cn.